# What is the name of the symbol of integration $d(\cdot)$ in $\int_a^bf(x)\,d(\cdot)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, soft-question, notation

Sorry if this already has an answer. It would not surprise me, but I just could not find it.

What is the name of whatever comes after the "$d$" in an integral?

**Examples:**

$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$$

What is $x$ or $dx$ called?

$$\int_a^b f(g)\,dg$$

What is $g$ or $dg$ called?

Comment: $x$ is the *dummy variable*, $dx$ is the *differential* of that dummy variable.

Comment: I could call it that, but it does not sound as formal as I would expect.

Comment: The admittedly more verbose (but also more politically correct) term _variable with a cognitive disability_ is also a possibility.

Comment: But in all seriousness, $x$ can also be called the _variable of integration_.

Comment: @aras indeed *disability* for the new political standard of correctness is very offensive and incorrect. Instead the new term is *special ability*.

Comment: Disability is so arbitrary and also defined primarily with usage or usefulness of something (by someone else) in mind. I would prefer a word that is descriptive but does not bust my intent of how to make it do what I want it to.

Comment: @mathreadler they were joking XD

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I know. I was also joking, daddy. xD

Comment: @aras : If "dummy variable" is offensive to dummies, then "bound variable" is the standard term to be used instead. "Dummy variable" is a good name for it, but unfortunately statisticians use the term for indicator variables and things similar to those, and those are not bound variables at all.

Comment: The $x$ in $\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x)\,dx,$ the $k$ in $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n a_k,$ the $u$ in $\displaystyle \lim_{u\to0} \frac{\sin u} u,$ the $\varepsilon$ in $\forall\varepsilon>0\  \exists\delta>0\ \cdots\cdots,$ are all bound variables, also called dummy variables. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $x$ in $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx$ is normally just called the *integration variable*. The $dx$ is called a *differential*.